# Refresh body tag if file input changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a local non server webpage called DisplayItems.html which pulls a list from another webpage called items.html. I currently had it set up where DisplayItems refreshes its body every x seconds in case items.html got updated. I am trying to lean towards checking if the input has changed every few seconds. If so, refresh the body of DisplayItems, if not, don't refresh. How could I go along of doing this?

DisplayItems.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scroll.css">
<script src="jquery1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_12_4 = $.noConflict(true);
var currentvar;
var oldvar = jQuery_1_12_4('#text').load("items.html"); 
<!--
function Refresh() {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);");
}
window.setInterval(function Checkforchange(){
  currentvar = jQuery_1_12_4('#text').load("items.html"); 
  if (currentvar != oldvar)
  currentvar = oldvar;
  Refresh();
}, 5000);
//   -->
</script> 
</head>
<body  onload="JavaScript:Refresh();">

<ul class='marquee' id="text">
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_1_12_4('#text').load("items.html");
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Items.html

```
<li>new item1</li>
<li>senario2</li>
<li>senario3</li>
```

Comment: Question, why not simply iframe the page that changes into the other page?

Comment: @NathanielFlick It is because Items.html is generated via excel and couldn't use a .txt file to correlate it due to security issues. I used IFrame with it embedded previously and ended up having more issues with it, than anything.

Comment: `setTimeout("location.reload(true);");` makes no sense. So your option is to use Ajax to fetch the page and check to see if it has changed and load does not return the html, so your check is not checking the response... `console.log(currentvar)` will show you that.

Comment: If the html file is viewable in a browser, then it can be viewable in an iframe. Are you saying the html file isn't viewable in a browser?

Comment: @NathanielFlick I'm saying I have no interest in Iframe unless you think you could potentially provide a good example of Iframe used in this scenario to refresh if Items.html list has changed.

Comment: I added code below that does exactly that every 5 seconds using ajax. Is there a reason you don't want to use ajax?

Comment: Nope! I was unaware of the GET ajax call functionality,  and am looking into it further currently. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Using your html (get rid of the refresh in the body though, and use Jquery, obviously).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Checkforchange() {

        $.get("/refresh/items.html", function (data) {

            if ($('#text').html() !== data) {
                $('#text').html(data);
                window.setTimeout(Checkforchange, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        Checkforchange();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: @Brandon did this solve the problem? If so, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark so people know that you've found a solution and it works and gives some reputation to both the answerer and you. There is no obligation to do this. Let me know if it doesn't work or requires further explanation too. Thanks!